# Why g++ isn't performing structure packing here?

Tags: c++, structure, padding, sizeof, memory-alignment

Consider following program:

```
#include <iostream>
struct __attribute__((__packed__)) mystruct_A
{
   char a;
   int b;
   char c;
}x;
int main()
{
    std::cout<<sizeof(x)<<'\n';
}
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-structure-packing) I understood following:

- Structure packing suppresses structure padding, padding used when
  alignment matters most, packing used when space matters most.
- Structure Packing, on the other hand prevents compiler from doing
  padding

I am on 32 bit environment & using Windows 7 OS. The 1st answer of linked question says that above code would produce structure of size 6 on a 32-bit architecture.

But when I compiled it using g++ 4.8.1 it gives me 9 as an output. So, is structure packing not happening completely here? 
Why extra 3 bytes are there in output?
sizeof char is always 1. Sizeof int is 4 on my compiler. So, sizeof above struct should be 1+4+1=6 when structure is packed.

I tried it on [here](http://ideone.com/rLN8t1). It gives me expected output 6.

Is there any role of processor or it depends only on Compiler?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: please attach the link if you test it on clang.

Comment: I tested it on my Macbook, 64-bit, Clang 3.5.

Comment: @AndreyNasonov: not working. It still gives 9 as output

Comment: are you on x86 CPU? Also, which compiler? (there are two different ports of g++ to windows 32, mingw and mingw-w64)

Comment: Try `__attribute__((__packed__, aligned(1)))`

Comment: http://ideone.com/2zP67K outputs 6. More compilers https://goo.gl/nIJ6bg

Comment: @M.M: I am on mingw-w-64. Orwell Dev C++ IDE. g++ version 4.8.1.

Comment: Using mingw-w64-i686-gcc 5.2 with any of the `__attribute__((packed))` variants mentioned here, I get size 9. Using mingw-w64-i686-clang 3.7 and the same attributes I get size 6. Using g++ again with `#pragma pack(push, 1) / #pragma pack(pop)` around the struct, I also get size 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

attribute packed is [broken on mingw32 compilers](//gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52991). Another option is to use
[pragma pack](//msdn.microsoft.com/library/2e70t5y1):

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct mystruct_A {
  char a;
  int b;
  char c;
} x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution here worked for me: https://wintermade.it/blog/posts/__attribute__packed-on-windows-is-ignored-with-mingw.html, which is to add `-mno-ms-bitfields` to the compiler flags.